# How to read an element in an array and see if it matches with a target string despite double letters

Tags: arrays, string

so I'm trying to find the amount of times a String is present in an array. So if I had an array of {AB, ABBBB, AAAABBB, AC} and I had a target String of AB, the frequency of the String AB would be 3 in the array. The program would disregard the repeating ABBBB and AAAABBBB and just read these element as AB. I have my code changing the duplicated sequence into a non-repeating sequence and then comparing that to the target with an if statement, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. `It is just returning back a zero value, when there should be a number.

This is the code:

```
public static int findFreqWithMutations (String target, String [] arr) {

    int count=0;
        for (String s:arr) {
            String ans= "";
            for (int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++) {

                if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1)) {
                 ans= ans + s.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        if (ans == target) {
            count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
     }
            `
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the assumption this is Java by the context clues.

Looks like you're getting wrapped up in searching the String character by character. Take advantage of `String.contains` and the [Stream API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)

```
public static int findFreqWithMutations (String target, String[] arr) {
     return Arrays.stream(arr)
                .mapToInt(item -> item.contains(target) ? 1 : 0)
                .sum();
}
```

**EDIT**

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835240/how-to-read-an-element-in-an-array-and-see-if-it-matches-with-a-target-string-de/#comment59337781_35835283) brought up a good point, I don't have enough context to know if **AB** should be considered a hit on **AAABBBCCC** perhaps that **ABC** would be the only applicable hit. Futhermore, **AB** wouldn't be a hit for **AAABBBCCC** as the string compiles down to **ABC**.

If this is the case, here's an alternative approach that maps each string to a string with only the **distinct** characters.

```
public static int occurrences(String[] array, String target) {
     return Arrays.stream(array)
                .map(item -> item.codePoints().distinct().collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString())
                .mapToInt(item -> item.equals(target) ? 1 : 0)
                .sum();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is quite what the OP was after, in that it discards order etc. If you're right that this is Java, maybe it is just because you need to use String.equals() to compare the string contents (instead of == which checks reference equality I believe).

Comment: In her example AAAABBBB read as AB, I think contains is the approach.

Comment: Hard to know without more context, but as described I don't think eg AAABBBCCC should count as a hit for AB, only ABC.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Let me write up an alternative approach.